# How do I confirm I'm using the right chromedriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I came in to the office yesterday morning to find that my Capybara tests couldn't interact with Chrome. I'm seeing

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
```

Googling around revealed that this was likely caused by an out-of-date `chromedriver` or `selenium-webdriver`, which sounded very plausible, since neither had been updated in a long time (I think `chromedriver` was at `2.2` and `selenium-webdriver` was at `2.35.1`), and since Chrome auto-updated to `32.0.1700.77` on January 14, that seemed like good solid evidence to me.

So I've updated `selenium-webdriver` to `2.39.0`. Figuring out what version of `chromedriver` I had been using actually turned out to be more difficult. I had a version of `chromedriver` sitting in my Downloads directory that I *thought* my code was referring to, but I couldn't find my Downloads directory in the `PATH` (I'm using OS X by the way). I tried replacing this file with version `2.8` from [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html), but it had no effect. I became skeptical that the version in my Downloads directory was the version that was being used in the first place, so I used brew to install it. `brew info chromedriver` now yields:

```
chromedriver: stable 2.8
http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/
/usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.8 (2 files, 21M) *
    Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/chromedriver.rb
```

Looks good. My `PATH` contains `/usr/local/bin`, which has a `chromedriver` link to the location brew installed to. As far as I understand it, this should allow my automation to detect and launch the `chromedriver`.

Unfortunately, my issue is still unresolved. I remain `unable to discover pages`. Can anyone confirm that I've done what one normally does to set up the `chromedriver`?

**Side Question:** After downloading `chromedriver 2.8` directly and also installing it with `brew`, I tried launching both the downloaded version and the `brew` version separately to confirm that either version could launch successfully. I'm certain they are both in fact version `2.8`, but when I launch either one the console says:

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.2) on port 9515
```

Is that normal? I certainly wasn't expecting it to say `v2.2`, but there are no other versions apart from `2.8` installed by brew (so I doubt `brew` is accidentally using the older version), and when I run the file I downloaded directly, I'm quite sure it's version `2.8` from the Chromedriver website. Is this an oversight on their part, or does `v2.2` refer to something else, unlikely though that may seem?

Comment: What's your full PATH? The one of the user who runs chromedr I mean. Also, in order to tell what the version of chromedriver is, it should have a '-v' flag

Comment: My suggestion dont use brew to install chromedriver and I use this PATH /usr/bin/ instead /usr/local/bin/ download chromedriver from here http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/chromedriver_mac32.zip unzip it and put it on PATH

Answer (score 25):

It would be tricky to verify the chrome driver version frequently when you download it with `homebrew`. I would suggest downloading the driver and maintaining it in a folder mapped in your PATH.

So that maintaining or identifying the driver version will be easy with the below steps:

1. Go to the folder where you have chromeDriver
2. Open command prompt pointing the folder
3. run: `chromeDriver -v`

Comment: Fair comment. However, I'm running on Windoze and wanted to know the version of chromedriver I was running. Google brought me here and the answer was very useful. Hence, it's an upvote from me.

Comment: How we can get this (Browser Driver version) using python ??

Answer (score 0):

ChromeDriver is [at version 2.16 now](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).  I would recommend manually updating your driver instead of updating with whatever older version that homebrew wants to update you to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line: `pip freeze` to list down all packages you have installed with their version.
Or you also can use `pip show <package name>` to check the details of the package, which also includes package version.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `chrome://version` for checking your chrome driver version.

Now it's time to check the latest release version. So click here [latest release version](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE)

Compare between;